# Can't keep fragments live through changing orientation or Saving fragment UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have an app that uses SherlockActionBar and switches between dynamic fragments through ActionItems in the Action Bar.

The problem is that i can't save the fragment states and their UI data.

This is the FragmentActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private LocationFragment locationFragement;
private HomeFragment homeFragment;
private SettingsFragment settingsFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    locationFragement = new LocationFragment();
    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();

    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.home:

        fragTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, homeFragment);            
        break;

    case R.id.location:

        fragTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, locationFragement);
        break;

    case R.id.settings:

        fragTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment);
        break;

    }
    fragTransaction.commit();
    return true;
}
```

Firstly, I tried to call to a single instance of the fragments, only to encounter NullPointerExceptions every time i did in the onOptionsItemSelected switch block

```
  fragTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragmentClassName);
```

while the fragment instantiation was under

```
 if(savedInstanceState == null){
        locationFragement = new LocationFragment();
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        }
```

The fragments would not have created under orientation change obviously, and i couldn't figure anyway i could keep them instantiated. So i decided to create them anew every onCreate (which is bad but i wanted something to work) and save the UI data just to pass it back to the fragment.

This is one of the fragments, the other 2 are the same:

```
public class LocationFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private View myView;
private CheckBox myCheckBok;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.d("LocationFragment", "onCreate running");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("LocationFragment", "onCreateView running");

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
    myCheckBok = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.mapFragmentCheckBox);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        myCheckBok.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isChecked"));
    }

    return myView;

}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    Log.d("LocationFragment", "onResume running");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    Log.d("LocationFragment", "onPause running");

    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    boolean isChecked = myCheckBok.isChecked();     
    outState.putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked);

    Log.d("LocationFragment", "onSaved Instant running");

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I'm saving the checkbox's state, when i pass through the icons the checkbox state is saved and also through orientation change. BUT, when i change orientation, press another icon (or press the same one) and return to my fragment, the state isn't saved. I realized this is caused due to onSavedInstanceState not running when i change to another fragment (thus not saving or passing the checkBox data).

I haven't found answers anywhere on how to save correctly UI data from fragments (just through savedInstanceState doesn't cut it for my purposes) or how to manage several fragment instantiations while changing them. I know that each time i change a fragment, all it's data
is saved automatically by the system, but can't seem to get it to work.

Please help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not using a Tablistener: onTabSelected/ onTabUnselected ? I save my data in shared prefs and my approach seems to work fine. The Google doc on this is good and equally applicable for ABS:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @IanB Thank you for your comment. It did occur to me initially to use tabs, and i know it works. The shared-prefs is a good idea. Unfortunately, that still doesn't address my questions directly on how to use Action Items as means to change fragments. Perhaps my entire approach is faulty and i should stick to tabs.

Comment: also, i cannot control where the action bar will locate the tabs: on landscape the tabs will be on the same bar and on portrait they will take another line. I need all the icons to be on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not part of the problem but you should be aware that the use of `onSaveInstanceState` is not needed for [saving a View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#saveEnabled) state. Android does that for you already as long as there's an ID to the View.

Seems like the problem you are facing is that you are not restoring the fragments from their `FragmentManager`. The fragments are there, but you simply didn't go to the `FragmentManager` and brought them once the `onCreate` has happened again.

This code should go in the `onCreate`:

```
    // Try and fetch the fragments from the manager
    locationFragement = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(LOCATION_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    homeFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HOME_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    settingsFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // If the fragment weren't found - meaning it's the first time the activity was 
    // started, create them
    if (locationFragement == null)  locationFragement = new LocationFragment();
    if (homeFragment == null)       homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    if (settingsFragment == null)   settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
```

And, whenever you are adding/removing/replacing a fragment, make sure to add him with the TAG, i.e.

```
    // EXAMPLE HOW TO USE A REPLACE WITH A TAG
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, 
                                      locationFragement, LOCATION_FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks! that worked out the problem of the instances greatly.

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't find more explanation about this on SO and online, but your post was extremely helpful to me.